# How to upload jpg to google drive using google drive api?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a jpg file onto google drive using the api but i'm not having much luck. Although the code does run without errors, the "image" saved in my google drive is untitled and doesn't actually contain data.

Here's how I'm doing it right now in Python:

```
post_body = "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id={}&client_secret={}&refresh_token={}".format(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token)

r = requests.post(refresh_url, data=post_body, headers={"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

r_json = json.loads(r.text)
access_token = r_json["access_token"]

media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype="image/jpeg", resumable=True)

body = {
        "name" : filename,
        "mimeType" : "image/jpeg"
       }

drive_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media"
drive_r = requests.post(drive_url, data=body, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-type": "image/jpeg"})
```

When I print drive_r.text, the response I'm getting back is this:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1Vt4gP***************",
 "name": "Untitled",
 "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your script, I understood that you want to upload a file to Google Drive without using googleapis for Python. In this case, I would like to propose the following modification.

### Modification points:

- In your script, the data from the file is not included in the request body.
- You use `uploadType=media`. But it seems that you want to include the file metadata. In this case, please use `uploadType=multipart`.

### Pattern 1:

If the file size you want to upload is less than 5 MB, you can use the following script. `uploadType=multipart` is used.

#### Modified script:

```
import json
import requests

access_token = r_json["access_token"] # This is your script for retrieving the access token.
filename = '###'  # Please set the filename with the path.

para = {"name": filename}
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json'),
    'file': open(filename, "rb")
}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token},
    files=files
)
print(r.text)
```

### Pattern 2:

If the file size you want to upload is more than 5 MB, you can use the following script. `uploadType=resumable` is used.

#### Modified script:

```
import json
import os
import requests

access_token = r_json["access_token"] # This is your script for retrieving the access token.
filename = '###'  # Please set the filename with the path.

filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
params = {
    "name": filename,
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
}
r1 = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
    headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data=json.dumps(params)
)
r2 = requests.put(
    r1.headers['Location'],
    headers={"Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(filesize - 1) + "/" + str(filesize)},
    data=open(filename, 'rb')
)
print(r2.text)
```

### Note:

- These sample scripts supposes that your access token can be used for uploading the file to Google Drive.

### Reference:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)